# Need to understand how the integrating factor is found

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given

\begin{align}
y &= \frac{a}{b} \left(1 - e^{-bx} \right) \\
\implies y’ &= \frac{a}{b} \cdot b e^{- bx} \\
&= ae^{- bx} \\
\implies y’ &= a \left(1 - \frac{by}{a} \right) \\
&= a - by
\end{align}

Perfectly logical. No problem at all.

But I have no clue at all how to go in reverse from

$$y’ = a - by$$

to the solution $y$. I think I need to find an integrating factor, but how? I also thought about a characteristic equation. Is that the way to go?

This is probably an obvious question, but all I know about differential equations, I picked up on my own rather than from a course or a text. I understand separable equations, exact equations, and characteristic equations, but finding integrating factors is *terra incognita*.

Comment: $y'=a-by$ is separable $$\frac{dy}{a-by}= dx \implies \ln (a - by) = - b x + C \implies \dots$$ or can be [integrated using an integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations) as you stated $$y' + by = a \implies \text{IF} = \exp \left(\int b dx \right) = \exp \left( bx\right) \implies e^{bx} y' + be^{bx}y = ae^{bx} \implies \dots$$ or can be solved by finding the homogeneous (by making the ansatz $y_{h} = e^{\lambda x}$ and deriving the characteristic equation) and particular ($y_{b}=A=\text{constant}$) solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a blind spot on the separabilty; I would have wasted hours on that. I shall have to think about the integrating factor logic. But again, thank you.

Comment: Oh, and thanks as well to the edits to put the question in LaTeX. I tried quite a few delimiters to invoke it, but none worked.

Comment: The integrating factor is simply $e^{bx}$

Comment: Ahh, the coefficient of y becomes the coefficient of x in the exponential. Always obvious once the light bulb turns on. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an ODE of the form $y' + fy = g,$ where $f$ and $g$ are given functions, then the integrating factor is $e^{F},$ where $F$ is a primitive function of $f,$ i.e. $F'=f$:
$$
e^F(y'+fy) = (e^Fy)'^.
$$